# Some music metadata/tags dissapeared after copying to micro sd

Tags: external-sd, file-system, partitions, music, id3-tag

I tried copying my large music library from my internal storage to my external micro sd card, only to find 50% of my album art went missing, some artist and album info is gone, while the songs themselves are fine. Tried copying them back to my computer just to check and there the tags where intact. I've tried converting every id3 tag to a specific version to see if that might resolve the issue, but it didn't. Which got me thinking, could it be the sd card? I mean it's not damaged, i just bought it, it's brand new. But perhaps the filesystem of the sd card is somehow different from the one in internal storage, and doesn't support some of the tags..? I'm not an expert when it comes to filesystems, so any help would be appreciated.

I tried to check the files on the sd card from both 2 file managers (google files & ES File Explorer) and Rocket Music Player. I'm running Android 9 and formatted my micro sd card as usaul through the settings app. I'm using an motorola moto e6 plus. My device is NOT rooted.